# Trying to create 3 columns with bootstrap and wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create 3 columns with bootstrap and Wordpress. I want my category posts to be in 3 columns. But instead of 3 columns, when I view the category page, they're in one column, stacked on top of each other. What am I doing wrong? This is my archive.php template

```
<?php if(have_posts() ): while(have_posts()): the_post();?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 post-card">

            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('blog-small');?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>" class="img-fluid mb-3 img-thumbnail">

<?php endif;?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><h2 class="h2 text-center mb-3"><?php the_title();?></h2>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="btn btn-success">Read more</a>
    </div>
</div> </div>
```

Comment: your ```while loop``` should be exactly before the ```col-md-4``` div class and not on top of the ```container``` div class.

Comment: @WanPeninsula Thanks for your reply. I changed the while loop to where you suggested, but it didn't fix the problem. See screenshot here: https://gyazo.com/f87601a7e9df799cdd97a3a06a8f1d05

Comment: just to be clear, ```if statement``` should be above the container and the while loop above the col cards. this loops through the cards if it has a post with the number of post.

Comment: @WanPeninsula Yeah, that's what I have done. Code here: https://pastebin.com/XBSG3Sde

Comment: Check code here. [image](https://pasteboard.co/Jc1mWZh.png)

Comment: ```endwhile``` should be after the closing ```div``` of the col card. check screenshot in above link

Comment: @WanPeninsula It's working, thank you! I hadn't changed the endwhile at the moment. Thank you very much!